# Why am I unable to open my dialog modally in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want a dialog to remain opened while some data is being fetched from the server. This is my code:

```
(async()=>{
    document.getElementById("dialog").showModal();
    if(condition1 is true){
        await server_call1();
    }
    if(condition2 is true){
        await server_call2();
    }
    if(condition3 is true){
        await server_call3();
    }
    document.getElementById("dialog").close();
})();
```

All the `server_call()` are independent of each other. Upon executing the code, this error keeps popping up in my console:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'showModal' on 'HTMLDialogElement': The element already has an 'open' attribute, and therefore cannot be opened modally.

How do I resolve this issue? Please help me.

**EDIT:** This is my `html`:

```
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p style="font-family: cursive;">Fetching results, please wait.. </p>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Post html too.  `The element already has an 'open' attribute`

Comment: I have posted. Please see

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that problem: https://jsfiddle.net/gev6k95s/

Comment: As @Ivar example there is nothing wrong with that code, is it possible that the function `server_call*` calls a dialog?

Answer (score 7):

I just put a call to close before every call to open e.g.

```
dialog.close();
dialog.showModal();
```

Throwing an exception for opening twice is strange behavior i think

Answer (score 0):

From the mdn docs about `HTMLDialogElement.showModal()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal

> InvalidStateError DOMException Thrown if the dialog is already open (i.e. if the open attribute is
> already set on the  element).

Here's your code working as expected in a live snippet:

```js
async function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

async function server_call(){
  await sleep(500);
}

(async()=>{
  document.getElementById("dialog").showModal();    
  await server_call();
  await server_call();
  await server_call();
  document.getElementById("dialog").close();
})();
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p style="font-family: cursive;">Fetching results, please wait 2 seconds.. </p>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I created a dialog in JS only.

To solve this, I added the dialog I just created to the DOM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).